# Выровнять блок по центру относительно окна браузера средствами JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть блок:

```
    <div data-index="24" style="border-radius: 0px; padding: 20px; background: none 0% 0% repeat scroll rgb(0, 0, 0); transform: scale(0, 0); transition-property: -moz-transform; transform-origin: 0% 50% 0px; width: 380px; left: 563.906px; top: 321.188px; display: block;" class="hs-tooltip">
     <div style="border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);" class="hs-arrow hs-arrow-left"></div>
     <div class="hs-tooltip-buffer hs-tooltip-buffer-left "></div>
     <h3 style="color: #2b2a2c;font-size: 20px;font-family: sans-serif;font-weight: 700;line-height: 30px;margin-bottom: 20px;">Infused Chocolate</h3>
     <p style="color: #2b2a2c;font-size: 15px;font-family: serif;font-weight: 300;line-height: 25px;"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Image-28-Chocolates.jpg"><br>Discover a wide selection of infused chocolates, including major brands and artisan pieces in both traditional doses and microdoses.<br><a href="#">View The Menu</a></p><i class="close"></i>
    </div>
```

Он выводится как popup, нужно чтоб он всегда отображался по центру окна браузера. Ширина у него фиксированная 380px, высота - динамическая. Также нужно чтоб при скроле вверх или вниз он скрывался.

Делал так, не получается

```
.homepage .pin-overlay + .hs-tooltip {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%!important;
    left: 50%!important;
    margin-top: -25%;
    margin-left: -190px;
}
```

Я уже даже нашел:

- window.innerWidth; //возвращает ширину окна
- window.innerHeight; //возвращает высоту окна

центр скорее всего будет возвращает `window.innerWidth / 2;` и `window.innerHeight / 2;`

Comment: Если ширина фиксированая - не лутше дать позиционировать абсолютно или fixed - left:50%; margin-left:190px;?

Comment: я делал так, но по какой-то причине он все равно позиционируется относительно высоты секции

Comment: `fixed` тут бесмысленно, вам ведь нужно чтобы при скролле он скрылся. Должет быть абсолютно спозиционирован

Comment: я пытался сделать стилями, но результата не добился, поэтому решил, что меня спасет в этом случае JS вычислением высоты и ширины экрана

Comment: эмм.. просто можно в стилях написать left:calc(50% - 190px) без вских там margin или скриптов

Comment: А вот про скрол можно поподробнее? В каком смысле "скрвался".. Чтоб он при прокрутке уезжал вместе со страницей или просто пропадал?

Comment: По горизонтали нет проблемы выровнять, проблема по вертикали выровнять, относительно окна и скрыть при скроле (скрывался/пропадал)

Answer (score 1):

Делается без js, средствами css:

```
.name{
    transform: translate(50%,50%);
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Сам блок должен находится **вне** секций с явно заданным позиционированием (absolute,relative,fixed) иначе он будет позиционироваться относительно них.

Лучше всего помещать такие блоки в верх DOM, например перед закрытием тега body.

*Такие цепочки классов не есть хороший подход. Рекомендую ознакомится с чем-то типо БЭМ*

Comment: В данном случае нет такой возможности вынести из секции, там плагин wp создаем точки, у каждой из точки свои координаты, высота секции примерно 1700px, таких точек порядка 20 шт и у каждой свой попап

Comment: @eugene_v тогда можете поменять `top:50%` на `top:50vh`.
Я не до конца понимаю вашу проблему, но мне кажется это может сработать.

Comment: Я понимаю, что это сложно понять. По этому и считаю, что если написать JS и свойствами JS получить значение ширины и высоты экрана, имея эти данные спозиционировать блок и добавить блоку еще пару строк кода скрыть его во время прокрутки. Я это так себе представляю

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $block = $("#block"),
    ww = $(window).width(),  // $("window").width()
    wh = $(window).height(); // $("window").heigth()
    
$block.offset({
    'top'  : wh / 2 - $block.height() / 2,
    'left' : ww /2 - $block.width() / 2
});
```

```css
#block{
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="block"></div>
```